# Matrix Idempotency Questions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra, idempotents

[image: Question image]

Firstly I apologise for the use of an image but I am still unfamiliar with using the math text on here.

So I am currently studying linear algebra at second year level and have been working on this question.

I have proved a) by squaring the matrix and obtaining that it is equal to the original matrix.

I have also shown b) by saying that

$$(I-B)^2= I^2 - 2IB + B^2$$

Which then equates to $I - B$ due to the fact that $I^2=I$ and $B^2=B$ for Idempotency.

I have also shown that for c) the determinants may only equal 0 or 1 by saying:

$det(C^2)= det(C)$

$det(c)* (det(c) - 1)=0$

However I'm now stuck on how to approach questions d) and e).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hint for (d): What's the relation between the matrix of $S\circ S'$ and the matrices of $S$ and $S'$?.

Comment: hint for (e): Is $E$ idempotent? Recall the hint for (d).

Comment: Yes e) is idempotent as when squared it returns the original matrix but I'm not sure what the relation is between the linear maps. Is it because they both represent idempotent matrices?

Comment: Do you know that if $T:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ has matrix $A$ and $T':\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ has matrix $B$, then $T\circ T'$ has matrix $A\cdot B$?

Comment: I didn't know that no. So am I looking to multiply the matrix D by In - D?

Comment: Try to show this property first.

Comment: So I have looked throughout my notes and found the principle that you are talking about (theorem 4.12) but it simply just states that this is fact and does not have proof behind it in the notes. So I assume I have to state this theorem first to use this condition.

Comment: Would you be able to expand your comment a bit more. I'm sorry but I'm not really grasping what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand my comments as required.

For (d): If $D$ is the matrix of $S$ and $I_n-D$ of $S'$, then the matrix of $S\circ S'$ is $$D(I_n-D)=D-D^2=D-D=0$$
so $S\circ S'$ is the null aplication.

For (e): As the matrix of $T$, $E$, is idempotent, then $E^2=E$. Also the matrix of $T^{9001}$ is $$E^{9001}=E^2 \cdot E^{8999}=E\cdot E^{8999}=E^{9000}=\ldots=E$$
so $T^{9001}=T$.

Comment: Thank you for expanding. Between the response time I learned about the further steps for d) and e) but did not know that S o S' was called a null application, so that's great to know!  However I'm still unsure  what it means to actually deduce/find the linear map. For instance what notation or words should I be writing?

Comment: Well, the name "null" i think it is not standard.... but it means the application that maps every vector to zero.

Comment: Okay yeah I get you. So when I'm answering that question do I just state "the linear map composition takes every vector and transforms it into the zero vector" and is the associated matrix just the 0 matrix by any size nxn?